# Passing psql query from perl into string

Tags: sql, linux, perl, psql

Currently I have a perl script that accesses our database, performs certain queries and prints output to the terminal. Instead, I would like to output the results into a template latex file before generating a pdf. For most of my queries I pull out numbers and store these as scalar variables (eg how often a particular operator carries out a given task). eg.

```
foreach $op (@operator) {
    $query = "SELECT count(task_name) FROM table WHERE date <= '$date_stop' and 
              date >= '$date_start' and task=\'$operator[$index]\';";

    #execute query
    $result=$conn->exec($query);
    $conres = $conn->errorMessage;
    if ($result->resultStatus eq PGRES_TUPLES_OK) {
        if($result->ntuples > 0) {
            ($task[$index]) = $result->fetchrow;
        }
        printf("$operator[$index] carried out task: %d\n", $task[$index]);   
    } else {
        die "Failed.\n$conres\n\n";
        exit -1;
    }
    $index++;
} 
printf("**********************************\n\n");
```

In the final report I will summarise how many times each operator completed each task in a table. In addition to this there will also be some incidents which must be reported. I can print these easily to the terminal using a command such as

```
$query = "SELECT operator, incident_type from table_name WHERE incident_type = 'Y' 
          and date <= '$date_stop' and date >= '$date_start';";
$result=$conn->exec($query);
$conres = $conn->errorMessage;
if ($result->resultStatus eq PGRES_TUPLES_OK) {
    if($result->ntuples > 0) {
        $result->print(STDOUT, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, "\t", "", "");
    }
} else {
    die "Failed.\n$conres\n\n";
    exit -1;
}
```

An example of the output of this command is

```
operator  |   incident_type
-----------------------------
AB        |  Incomplete due to staff shortages
-------------------------------
CD        |  Closed due to weather
-----------------------------
```

How can I make my perl script pass the operator names and incidents into a string array rather than just sending the results to the terminal?

Comment: Are you using the DBI module? You should perhaps specify that.

Comment: It looks like you're not even using `strict`, and you're using `printf` and `exit` wrong. Then there's the pointless `\'` and the SQL injection issues. This does not make me want to take a closer look.

Comment: @TLP I use the Pg module. My script is a hack of another program used in the department and it is my first attempt at Perl and PSQL. melpomene - this is my first attempt at both languages and a hack of anothers code so there is bound to be many errors as it is a fairly steep learning curve. I use strict 'vars'. What is wrong with printf and exit?

Comment: The Pg module seems to be 13 years old, perhaps not the most up-to-date, though I suppose its possible it still works. You have multiple errors in your code, so my advice is to scrap it and start over, using the DBI module instead.

Comment: @moadeep You're using `printf` where `print` would suffice (`print "*****\n\n"`, `print "$operator[$index] carried out task: $task[$index]\n"`); you're using `printf` with a variable format string (`printf "$operator[$index] ..."`, format string injection bug); `exit` (at least on unixish OSes) only takes values between 0 and 255 (`exit -1` is nonsensical). If you're using `strict 'vars'`, then all of your variables have a too wide scope (globals?). You really should start each file with `use warnings; use strict;`.

Comment: @melpomene Don't forget using `$op` in the for loop, but using `$operator[$index]` to access the elements. And using `die` before `exit` is also rather a pointless exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider updating your script to use [`DBI`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm).  This is the standard for database connectivity in Perl.

DBI has a built in facility for inserting parameters into a query string. It is safer and faster than manually creating the string yourself.  Before the loop, do this once:

```
#dbh is a database handle that you have already opened.
my $query = $dbh->prepare(
    "SELECT count(task_name) FROM table WHERE date<=? and date>=? and task=?"
);
```

Then within the loop, you only have to do this each time:

```
$query->execute($date_stop,$date_start,$op);
```

Note that the parameters you pass to `execute` automatically get inserted in place of the `?`'s in your statement.  It handles the quoting for you.

Also in the loop, after you execute the statement, you can get the results like this:

```
my $array_ref = $query->fetchall_array_ref;
```

Now all of the rows are stored in a two-dimensional array structure. `$array_ref->[0][0]` would get the first column of the first row returned.

See the [DBI documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#fetchall_arrayref) for more information.

As others have mentioned, there are quite a few other mistakes in your code.  Make sure you start with `use strict; use warnings;`, and ask more questions if you need further help!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As it is a postgreSQL database, should I be using DBD:Pg driver to connect to the database?

Comment: @moadeep, I haven't used postgreSQL, but yes, that appears to be the correct driver.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of good feedback to your script, but nothing about your actual question.

> How can I make my perl script pass the operator names and incidents into a string array rather than just sending the results to the terminal?

Have your tried creating an array and pushing items to it?

```
my @array;
push (@array, "foo");
```

Or using nested arrays:

```
push (@array, ["operator", "incident"]);
```

Comment: I haven't but this looks exactly what I need. I have taken the feedback on board and I am currently rewriting my script from scratch and attempting to do it properly and following good perl convention. Thanks

Comment: My answer *does* show how to get the query results in an array (albeit using a different module).